# SharePoint 2010 Services on Server not showing some services on some servers

Tags: excel-services, service-applications, access-services

SharePoint 2010 Services on Server not showing some services on some servers

One server I can see all services, but when I change to a different server it only shows some services.

This is a 3 WFE and 2 App server farm, there are 3 servers that were part of the original farm and 2 that were added later, all 3 of the original servers show all services, but on the 2 newer ones they are missing some services, any thoughts are appreciated...

[Server1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN9fQ.png)

[image: Server2]

Comment: Are u std or enter edition? Try to run config wizard on the server missing services? What service are missing?

Comment: Enterprise, I ran the config wizard to no avail, Access Database Service
Excel Calculation Services
PerformancePoint Service
Visio Graphics Service

Comment: So ee services missing...what are role is server where services missing ?

Comment: Application server, I even checked registry to confirm

Comment: I know it's not possible, can you check sharepoint Sku on the missing server if they are ent or std?

Comment: Current License  
 SharePoint Server with Enterprise Client Access License

Comment: Are theses server doing anything?

Comment: Yes they're production servers, we are trying to decommission an older one and need to move the services to the new servers but I can't start the services when they're not available

Answer (score 0):

Run `Install-SPService` on the servers missing services.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: Under Manage Servers in Farm, are the Products listed identical (they should be, SharePoint shouldn't let you join servers to the farm that do not match up). Looking at the differences between your two servers, one is missing Enterprise features (ECS, VSG, PerfPoint).

Comment: they are identical, even the service registry keys are identical. I ran this (Get-SPServiceInstance -server name | sort TypeName | Format-Table -AutoSize) and the results are the same as Central Admin

Comment: How about running `Install-SPFeature -AllExistingFeatures`?

Comment: Didn't work either

Comment: Does `Get-SPProduct -Local` on each of the servers missing services do anything at all? Note that it may take a few minutes to register after completing that cmdlet.

Comment: Result:
ProductName                    Required   Missing              Servers
-----------                    --------   -------              -------
Microsoft SharePoint Server... True                            {}